# Exercício para sequenciar números com Struct

Tags: c, struct

Estou fazendo um exercício para sequenciar números, usando uma struct, porém o que está acontecendo é que no meu `for` a variável `i` está sendo incrementada de uma maneira muito estranha, na segunda passagem do `scanf`, seu valor passa a ser `104352`, ao invés de passar a ser `1`... Não consigo entender o porquê, mas imagino que seja o modo como declarei `numeros[]` na `struct`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int qtdeNumeros;
    int qtdeRepetidos;
    float numeros[];
}Sequencia;


int main()
{

    Sequencia sequencia;

    printf("Quantos numeros deseja colcoar na sequencia? ");
    scanf("%d", &sequencia.qtdeNumeros);

    for(int i=0; i < sequencia.qtdeNumeros; i++){
        printf("Digite o numero [%d]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &sequencia.numeros[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<sequencia.qtdeNumeros; i++){
        printf("Numeros [%d]: %f\n", i+1, sequencia.numeros[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não precisaria inicializar `sequencia`?

Comment: Inicializar em que sentido?

Comment: tipo assim:
`Sequencia *sequencia;
sequencia = malloc(sizeof(Sequencia));`

Comment: Eu até entendi o que tu quis dizer, porem não podemos usar malloc já que não foi um conceito aprendido

Comment: Então não tem como resolver desta forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está definido acho que não da prá fazer.

Seguindo a dica do "anônimo", o que é possível fazer é colocar um tamanho máximo
predefinido no array de floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 50

typedef struct
{
  int qtdeNumeros;
  int qtdeRepetidos;
  float numeros[ARRAY_SIZE];
} Sequencia;

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  Sequencia sequencia;

  for (;;)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* quantos numeros deseja colocar na sequencia? ");
    n = scanf("%d", &sequencia.qtdeNumeros);
    if (n != 1)
    {
      printf("* erro na entrada de dados, tente novamente...\n");
      continue;
    }
    if (sequencia.qtdeNumeros > ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
      printf("* numero muito grande, tente novamente...\n");
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  for (int i=0; i < sequencia.qtdeNumeros; i++)
  {
    printf("* digite o numero [%d]: ", i+1);
    for (;;)
    {
      n = scanf("%f", &sequencia.numeros[i]);
      if (n != 1)
      {
        printf("* erro na entrada de dados, tente novamente...\n");
        continue;
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i<sequencia.qtdeNumeros; i++)
    printf("* numeros [%d]: %f\n", i+1, sequencia.numeros[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! A solução deu uma ótima ajuda, poém acabei resolvendo de outra maneira um tanto quanto mais simples.

Comment: seria interessante você também colocar uma resposta com a solução que você usou

Comment: é que a resposta que eu usei modificaria totalmente o tipo da estrutura, não sei se agregaria muito, e como eu fiz o exercicio durante a lista, eu sobrescrevi ele com outro codigo :(

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
typedef struct{
    int qtdeNumeros;
    int qtdeRepetidos;
    float *numeros;
}Sequencia;


printf("Quantos numeros deseja colcoar na sequencia? ");
scanf("%d", &sequencia.qtdeNumeros);
sequencia.numeros = (float *) malloc(sequencia.qtdeNumeros * sizeof(float));
```

Se não puder utilizar alocação dinâmica declare o array numeros com um número arbitrariamente grande, por ex.: `float numeros[10000];` e teste se a quantidade lida não é maior que a declarada.